# how to pass context variable from a template to a view in django

Tags: python, django

I have one html page which shows me the list of all passengers reading it from db looks something like below and the code snippet below the image:

[image]

**Forms.py**

```
<form   action="{% url 'test' %}"   method="POST">
    {% for record in obj %}
<div class="container">
{% csrf_token %}
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">{{ record.id }}</div>
          <div class="col">{{ record.detination }}</div>
          <div class="col">{{ record.arrivaltime }}</div>
          <div class="col">{{ record.gender }}</div>
            <div class="col">{{ record.luggage  }}</div>
            <div class="col">{{ record.flag }}</div>
            <div class="col">{{ record.phonenum }}</div>
        <button id="button1">Request</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
    {% endfor %}
</form>
```

As you can see each entry has a request button associated to it,so on each single click i want that particular entry to get stored in Db.

I have a view which take the request from the template and should store those 7 parameters values which are inside div tags in db.

**Views.py**

```
def test(request):
        form = BlogCommentsForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
               form.save()
```

The problem is when i get the request in the view there are two problems i can see:

1. My form returns is_valid() as Flase.
2. all the object list getting
   passed rather than a single entry.

The results of request.POST were supposed to bejust for a single click of entry, butresulted in some dictionary like below having all the objects from the db than a single one

**Request.POST** gives me the result like :

```
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['sqvfMziME3T7L0VQOUF7H3Po3etfqmsvf4SbH57Fk28DkbiiGBa7dNQF2lazcM7W', 'sqvfMziME3T7L0VQOUF7H3Po3etfqmsvf4SbH57Fk28DkbiiGBa7dNQF2lazcM7W', 'sqvfMziME3T7L0VQOUF7H3Po3etfqmsvf4SbH57Fk28DkbiiGBa7dNQF2lazcM7W', ]}>
```

I don't exactly know where i am doing the things wrong. Can someone help me on this?

Comment: In your template form, where is the `name` tag for the fields you want to post to your service?

Comment: @RamyMohamed if i add it with div then it shows changes on the UI by adding text boxes with all the entries. I was trying to add like this.  <div class="col"><input name="record">{{ record.id }}</div>